# How to convert Dynamic 7 day rows into columns with t-sql

Tags: sql, t-sql

Background Info
I have a large table 400M+ rows that changes daily (one days data drops out an a new days data drops in) The table is partitioned on a 'day' field so there are 31 paritions.
Each row in the table has data similar to this:

```
ID, Postcode, DeliveryPoint, Quantity, Day, Month
1   SN1 1BG   A1               6        29    1
2   SN1 1BG   A1               1        28    1
3   SN1 1BG   A2               2        27    1
4   SN1 1BG   A1               3        28    1
5   SN2 1AQ   B1               1        29    12
6   SN1 1BG   A1               2        26    12
```

I need to pull out 7 days of data in the format:

```
Postcode, Deliverypoint, 7dayAverage, Day1,day2,Day3,Day4,Day5,Day6,Day7  
SN1 1BG      A1             2          0    1    2    1    3    4   0
```

I can easily extract the data for the 7 day period but need to create a columnar version as shown above.

I have something like this:

```
select postcode,deliverypoint,
sum (case  day when 23 then quantity else 0 end) as day1,
sum (case  day when 24 then quantity  else 0 end) as day2,
sum(case  day when 25 then quantity  else 0 end) as day3,
sum(case  day when 26 then quantity  else 0 end) as day4,
sum(case  day when 27 then quantity  else 0 end) as day5,
sum(case  day when 28 then quantity  else 0 end) as day6,
sum(case  day when 29 then quantity  else 0 end) as day7,
sum(quantity)*1.0/@daysinweek as wkavg
into #allweekdp
from maintable dp with (nolock)
where day in (select day from #days)
group by postcode,deliverypoint
```

where #days has the day numbers in the 7 day period.

But as you can see, I've hard-coded the day numbers into the query, I want to get them out of my temporary table #days but can't see a way of doing it (an array would be perfect here)

Or a I going about this in completely the wrong way ?

Kind Regards

Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what I would do is:

1. Convert the day and month columns into datetime values,
2. Get the first day of the week and day of the weekday (1-7) for each date, and
3. Pivot the data and group by the first day of the week

see here: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a8cea/19/0)

Answer (score 0):

As utexaspunk suggested, Pivot might be the way to go. I've never been comfortable with pivot and have preferred to pivot it manually so I control how everything looks, so I'm using a similar solution to how you did your script to solve the issue. No idea how the performance between my way and utexaspunk's will compare.

```
Declare @Min_Day Integer = Select MIN(day) as Min_Day From #days;

With Day_Coding_CTE as (
Select Distinct day
    , day - @Min_Day + 1 as Day_Label

From #days
)

, Non_Columnar_CTE as (
Select dp.postcode
    , dp.deliverypoint
    , d.day
    , c.Day_Label
    , SUM(quantity) as Quantity

From maintable dp with (nolock)
    Left Outer Join #days d
        on dp.day = d.day --It also seems like you'll need more criteria here, but you'll have to figure out what those should be
    Left Outer Join Day_Coding_CTE c
        on d.day = c.day
)

Select postcode
    , deliverypoint
    , SUM(Case
        When Day_Label = 1
            Then Quantity
            Else 0
        End) as Day1
    , SUM(Case
        When Day_Label = 2
            Then Quantity
            Else 0
        End) as Day2
    , SUM(Case
        When Day_Label = 3
            Then Quantity
            Else 0
        End) as Day3
    , SUM(Case
        When Day_Label = 4
            Then Quantity
            Else 0
        End) as Day4
    , SUM(Case
        When Day_Label = 5
            Then Quantity
            Else 0
        End) as Day5
    , SUM(Case
        When Day_Label = 6
            Then Quantity
            Else 0
        End) as Day6
    , SUM(Case
        When Day_Label = 7
            Then Quantity
            Else 0
        End) as Day7
    , SUM(Quantity)/@daysinweek as wkavg

From Non_Columnar_CTE

Group by postcode
    deliverypoint
```